# How to print multiple categories in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to pass multiple categories IDs through shortcode and it should print all the posts in that categories.

e.g. [myshortcode cat="1,2"]

but the problem that I have is that it only prints the posts from first category. I think I am not able to loop through the category IDs.

here's my code.

```
// define attributes
extract( shortcode_atts( array (
    'cat' => '',
    'orderby' => 'date',
), $atts ) );
```

Separate the IDS

```
 if($cat) {
        $args['category__in'] = array_map('intval',explode(',',$cat));
    }
```

Display the posts

```
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $query->have_posts() ){
        echo "<div class='row col-div investment-guides'>";
        while( $query->have_posts() ){

            $query->the_post();
            $id = get_the_ID();
            $page = get_post($id);
            $image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id);


           display_layout($page,$image); //calls the function below
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

Function to display individual posts

```
function display_layout($page,$image) {

    echo "<div class='col-sm-6  pair-cards'>
            <div class='sub-div'>
                <div class='card-img'>
                <a href='$page->post_name'><img src='$image' alt='$page->post_name'  /></a>
                </div>".
                    "<div class='entry-title'><a href='$page->post_name'>" .  $page->post_title  .  "</a></div>
                <div class='card-desc'>".
                    "<p>" . strip_tags($page->post_excerpt) ."</p>
                </div>
                <div class='read-more'>
                    <a href='$page->post_name'> Read More </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>";
}
```

var_dump($args)

```
 'posts_per_page' => string '-1' (length=2)
  'orderby' => null
  'category__in' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 2
```

var_dump($query)

```
object(WP_Query)[1984]
  public 'query' => 
    array (size=3)
      'posts_per_page' => string '-1' (length=2)
      'orderby' => null
      'category__in' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1
          1 => int 2
  public 'query_vars' => 
    array (size=65)
      'posts_per_page' => int -1
      'orderby' => null
      'category__in' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 1
          1 => int 2
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your full WP_query and it's args array please ?

Comment: sure. I've added it in the question. thanks

Comment: Why are IDs in category__in different in your args ?

Comment: its been fixed.

Comment: If you try this same WP_query, with same args, outside of your shortcode. Does it output correct posts? Hardcoding the category__in parameter.

Comment: I will try that and see.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in WordPress, you can create a custom shortcode that accepts multiple category IDs as parameters and then displays the posts from those categories. Here's how you can do it:

Open your theme's functions.php file (you can find it in your theme's directory).
Add the following code to register a custom shortcode:

```
// Custom shortcode to display posts from specified categories
function custom_category_posts_shortcode($atts) {
    // Extract shortcode attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'categories' => '', // Default value for categories parameter
    ), $atts);

    // Get category IDs from shortcode attribute
    $category_ids = explode(',', $atts['categories']);

    // Query posts from specified categories
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'category__in' => $category_ids,
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // -1 for all posts, adjust as needed
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    // Start output buffer
    ob_start();

    // Check if posts are found
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        // Start the loop
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            // Display post title, content, or any other desired information
            ?>
            <div class="post">
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <div class="post-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        // Restore original post data
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        echo 'No posts found.';
    }

    // Return buffered content
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('custom_posts_from_categories', 'custom_category_posts_shortcode');
```

This code registers a shortcode [custom_posts_from_categories] that accepts a parameter categories where you can specify comma-separated category IDs.

Now, you can use this shortcode in your WordPress content editor like this:

```
[custom_posts_from_categories categories="1,2,3"]
```